# This set is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

The subset $I = \{n ∈ \mathbb{Z}; \exists \,\,k \mbox{ such that }
16|n^k\}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: It seems that $I=2\Bbb Z$ the set of even numbers and therefor an ideal.

Comment: A question mark slapped on the end of a statement does not a question make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can prove the following more general fact: if $N>0$, $\{n\in\mathbb Z:\exists k\ge1\ N\mid n^k\}=\operatorname{rad}(N)\mathbb Z=$ [$\text{A007947}(N)\mathbb Z$](https://oeis.org/A007947).

For a prospective element of the set $n$, if $n$ does not have a prime factor of $N$, all its powers clearly cannot divide $n$. Conversely, if it has all prime factors, a high enough power of $n$ will have sufficiently many prime factors (with multiplicity) to match all of $N$'s prime factors and thus be a multiple of $N$. Since $N\mid 0$, the set described above is $\operatorname{rad}(N)\mathbb Z$.

The set in the question is equivalent to $2\mathbb Z$.